# How to modify HockeyApp update prompt and window

Tags: hockeyapp

I have implemented the HockeyApp iOS SDK and was able to launch my app and have it prompt me that a new update was available.

However, the "Update Available" prompt and window have strange text displayed.

See images attached.

Can anyone provide some direction on what the issue may be???

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you integrating the SDK? Which OS is this? iOS native or e.g. Xamarin?
The issue you're seeing means that the resources bundle was not correctly integrated and there is an issue with your build setup.

Comment: iOS - Thought I said that in the question.

I created a library that includes the HockeyApp-iOS SDK library.


https://github.com/timanrebel/HockeyApp

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry :) I was more interested if you're using the native SDK directly or through a wrapper like Xamarin or Cordova.

Comment: Lukas has identified the problem - missing the HockeySDKResources.bundle from the XCode project and/or the resources are not copied in build phase of xcode project. 


See [Wrong strings or "Missing HockeySDKResources.bundle" error](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/hockeyapp-for-ios#troubleshooting)

Comment: @newport99 you should add that as an answer to the question, then accept that answer, so this question can become answered instead of seeming like nobody has responded.

Comment: @john-gardner with all due respect, When someone leaves a comment, they do so because they want to leave a comment. If they wanted to answer, they would have posted an answer. The comment from Lukas was very helpful in pointing to the solution but you need intimate knowledge of how to accomplish what he is suggesting in order to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Newport99 that makes no sense.  you asked a question.  this is a Q&A site.  the answer, which you stated in the comment was "Lukas .. identified the problem.. and it was .. X" was the answer to your question, no?  put your "intimate" knowledge into the question or the answer then, so anyone else who has this problem can learn from your intimate knowledge, instead of leaving an open question here.